# How to express the orthogonal complement of a linearly transformed null space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let ${\mathcal A} = \mathrm{Null}(A)$ be the null space (kernel) of $A \in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n}$. Consider a linear map $T: {\mathbb R}^n \to {\mathbb R}^n$ (i.e., $T \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$), and ${\mathcal B} = T(\mathrm{Null}(A))$ be the transformed space. Then, there exists a $B \in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n}$ such that ${\mathcal B} = \mathrm{Null}(B)$.

My question is how to express $B$ by $A$ and $T$. Thanks!

PS: If $T$ is bijective (invertiable), then $B$ can be $AT^{-1}$. This can be verified by $(AT^{-1})(Tx) = 0$ where $x \in {\mathbb R}^n$.

Comment: One problem here is that $B$ is severely underdefined. For example, if the image of $T$ intersects $Null(A)$ then $B$ restricted to the intersection could be equal to $A$.

Comment: @Leo Yes, $B$ can equal $A$ (a special case of your example is $T$ is an identity matrix). So, different $T$ can result in different $B$, but it seems not easy to express $B$ by $A$ and $T$ when $T$ is non-singular.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just pick a basis for $\operatorname{Null(A)}$ and extend it to a basis for $\Bbb R^n$? I'm not sure you will be able to find a much nicer solution just in terms of $A$ and $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=T(I_n-A^+A)\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$. Then $T\ker(A)=T\operatorname{ran}(I_n-A^+A)=\operatorname{ran}(M)$. For every $B\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $\operatorname{ran}(M)\subseteq\ker(B)$ if and only if
$$
B=C(I_n-MM^+)\tag{1}
$$
for some $C\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$. Let $k=\operatorname{rank}(M)$. It follows that $\operatorname{ran}(M)=\ker(B)$ if and only if $(1)$ holds and
$$
\operatorname{rank}\left(C(I_n-MM^+)\right)=n-k.\tag{2}
$$
If $M=USV^T$ is a full singular value decomposition, every solution of $(2)$ is in the form of $C=\pmatrix{X&Y}U^T$, where $X\in\mathbb R^{m\times k}$ is arbitrary and $Y\in\mathbb R^{m\times (n-k)}$ is any matrix of full column rank. Such $Y$ can be chosen if and only if $m\ge n-k$. In particular, when $m\ge n$, we may just pick any $C$ of full column rank.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks very much for your help!